# Demystifying this command line build sequence

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5, moc

So far I've been sticking to the following procedure:
 - call qmake on the project
 - call make

But looking at the commands Qt Creator issues for a particular project (QML plugin) I detect another procedure:

To summarize before posting the full code, for a project with 2 headers and 2 cpp files I get 2 calls to g++, followed by a call to moc, another g++, another moc and finally 2 more calls to g++, in total 7 calls, 5 to g++ and 2 to moc.

Could perhaps someone be kind enough as to explain to me why are so many calls needed and what does each one do in particular? Naturally, I do have some ideas, I see two calls to the moc and two user classes, but I still don't understand the reason for all the calls and the reason for their particular ordering.

Here is the full code (formatted to make it more readable):

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++
-c
-Wno-psabi
-march=armv7-a
-mfloat-abi=softfp
-mfpu=vfp
-ffunction-sections
-funwind-tables
-fstack-protector
-fno-short-enums
-DANDROID
-Wa,--noexecstack
-std=gnu++0x
-O2
-mthumb
-Os
-fomit-frame-pointer
-fno-strict-aliasing
-finline-limit=64
-D_REENTRANT
-Wall
-Wno-psabi
-W
-fPIC
-DQT_NO_DEBUG
-DQT_PLUGIN
-DQT_QUICK_LIB
-DQT_QML_LIB
-DQT_NETWORK_LIB
-DQT_GUI_LIB
-DQT_CORE_LIB

-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++
-I..\plugin
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtQuick
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtQml
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtNetwork
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore
-I.
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include
-I.
-o plugin_plugin.obj ..\plugin\plugin_plugin.cpp

______________________________________________
arm-linux-androideabi-g++
-c
-Wno-psabi
-march=armv7-a
-mfloat-abi=softfp
-mfpu=vfp
-ffunction-sections
-funwind-tables
-fstack-protector
-fno-short-enums
-DANDROID
-Wa,--noexecstack
-std=gnu++0x
-O2
-mthumb
-Os
-fomit-frame-pointer
-fno-strict-aliasing
-finline-limit=64
-D_REENTRANT
-Wall
-Wno-psabi
-W
-fPIC
-DQT_NO_DEBUG
-DQT_PLUGIN
-DQT_QUICK_LIB
-DQT_QML_LIB
-DQT_NETWORK_LIB
-DQT_GUI_LIB
-DQT_CORE_LIB

-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++
-I..\plugin
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtQuick
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtQml
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtNetwork
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore
-I.
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include
-I.
-o myitem.obj
..\plugin\myitem.cpp

______________________________________________
moc.exe
-DQT_NO_DEBUG
-DQT_PLUGIN
-DQT_QUICK_LIB
-DQT_QML_LIB
-DQT_NETWORK_LIB
-DQT_GUI_LIB
-DQT_CORE_LIB

-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++
-I..\plugin -IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtQuick
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtQml
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtNetwork
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore
-I.
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include
-I.
-I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include
..\plugin\plugin_plugin.h -o moc_plugin_plugin.cpp

______________________________________________
arm-linux-androideabi-g++
-c
-Wno-psabi
-march=armv7-a
-mfloat-abi=softfp
-mfpu=vfp
-ffunction-sections
-funwind-tables
-fstack-protector
-fno-short-enums
-DANDROID
-Wa,--noexecstack
-std=gnu++0x
-O2
-mthumb
-Os
-fomit-frame-pointer
-fno-strict-aliasing
-finline-limit=64
-D_REENTRANT
-Wall
-Wno-psabi
-W
-fPIC
-DQT_NO_DEBUG
-DQT_PLUGIN
-DQT_QUICK_LIB
-DQT_QML_LIB
-DQT_NETWORK_LIB
-DQT_GUI_LIB
-DQT_CORE_LIB
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++
-I..\plugin
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtQuick
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtQml
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtNetwork
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore
-I.
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include
-I.
-o moc_plugin_plugin.obj
moc_plugin_plugin.cpp

______________________________________________
moc.exe
-DQT_NO_DEBUG
-DQT_PLUGIN
-DQT_QUICK_LIB
-DQT_QML_LIB
-DQT_NETWORK_LIB
-DQT_GUI_LIB
-DQT_CORE_LIB
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++
-I..\plugin -IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtQuick
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtQml
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtNetwork
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore
-I.
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include
-I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include ..\plugin\myitem.h -o moc_myitem.cpp

______________________________________________
arm-linux-androideabi-g++
-c
-Wno-psabi
-march=armv7-a
-mfloat-abi=softfp
-mfpu=vfp
-ffunction-sections
-funwind-tables
-fstack-protector
-fno-short-enums
-DANDROID
-Wa,--noexecstack
-std=gnu++0x
-O2
-mthumb
-Os
-fomit-frame-pointer
-fno-strict-aliasing
-finline-limit=64
-D_REENTRANT
-Wall
-Wno-psabi
-W
-fPIC
-DQT_NO_DEBUG
-DQT_PLUGIN
-DQT_QUICK_LIB
-DQT_QML_LIB
-DQT_NETWORK_LIB
-DQT_GUI_LIB
-DQT_CORE_LIB
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++
-I..\plugin -IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtQuick
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtQml
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtNetwork
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui
-IC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore
-I.
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include
-I..\..\..\Android\android-ndk-r9d\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include
-I. -o moc_myitem.obj
moc_myitem.cpp
del libplugin.so

______________________________________________
arm-linux-androideabi-g++
--sysroot=D:\Android\android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
-Wl,--no-undefined
-Wl,-z,noexecstack
-shared
-o
libplugin.so
plugin_plugin.obj
myitem.obj
moc_plugin_plugin.obj
moc_myitem.obj
-LD:\Android\android-ndk-r9d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a
-LD:\Android\android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-19/arch-arm//usr/lib
-LC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7\lib -lQt5Quick
-Lc:\Utils\android\ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a
-Lc:\Utils\android\ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib
-LC:\Utils\icu32_51_1_mingw48\lib -LC:\utils\postgresql\pgsql\lib
-LC:\utils\mysql\mysql\lib -LC:\Utils\pgsql\lib
-LC:\temp\opensll-android-master\openssl-android-master\lib
-LC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1_Android\5.2.1\android_armv7/lib
-lQt5Qml
-lQt5Network
-lQt5Gui
-lQt5Core
-lGLESv2
-lgnustl_shared
-llog
-lz
-lm
-ldl
-lc
-lgcc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you have three different processes running for various inputs and outputs. These namely are:

- compiler to compile source code into object files.
- meta object compiler to generate source code.
- linker to link all the object files together into a binary, in this case shared librarry.

#### Step 1

The first created an object file out of your plugin source code using g++.

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ ... -o plugin_plugin.obj ..\plugin\plugin_plugin.cpp
```

#### Step 2

The second created an object file out of your myitem.cpp source code using g++.

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ ... -o myitem.obj ..\plugin\myitem.cpp
```

#### Step 3

The third generated the necessary moc file for your plugin using moc.

```
moc.exe ... ..\plugin\plugin_plugin.h -o moc_plugin_plugin.cpp
```

#### Step 4

The fourth created the object for the previously generated moc source code using g++.

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ ... -o moc_plugin_plugin.obj moc_plugin_plugin.cpp
```

#### Step 5

The fifth generated the moc source code for your myitem.cpp source code using moc.exe.

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ ... ..\plugin\myitem.h -o moc_myitem.cpp
```

#### Step 6

The sixth created the object file for the previouly created moc file using g++.

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ ... -o moc_myitem.obj moc_myitem.cpp
```

#### Step 7

The seventh and last step linked the created object file in the previous steps together using g++ for linking:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ ... -shared -o libplugin.so plugin_plugin.obj myitem.obj
moc_plugin_plugin.obj moc_myitem.obj
```

These are all different steps working on different input and output files and then the file linkage happens for all of them. That is the reason why you got those commands run.

Comment: Why does the second to last g++ delete the `.so` file in the end?

Comment: @user2341104: to safely recreate it. What if you get a power cut before flushing the new content? It will be something undesired. If it cleans it up first, you will have anything and that is a clear sign of not having finished the run. But allow me to ask this: why would it matter for you there is a del in there?

Comment: I just wonder, after all the whole compilation process is about producing that `.so` file, you might see how it would make me curious if this file ends up "ready" and deleted the second to last step just to be created again in the last step. The whole order doesn't seem logical - why even attempting to create the library before it is "safe to"? Why isn't the moc running first? I get the feeling this process might have back-and-forth going redundancies. Isn't there a "more adequate" order in which the final result can be evaluated with less steps? E.g. similar to the "qmake, make" approach?

Comment: @user2341104: I think you do not completely understand what [building a library from source](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html) means and what [moc is meant to do](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/moc.html). Please read upon those topics. It is not productive to explain that to you from scratch in comments. But in short, you have to generate two source files, create 4 object files, and link them together. I cannot possibly understand what the problem is in here. What would you propose instead and what would be the benefit?